# Setting a stair design based on adjacent stairs and look direction

Tags: lua, minecraft, roblox

I am trying to automate a system that'd place stairs and change their facing and shape properties based on any adjacent stairs + the look direction that you place it in.

This is being done in Roblox Lua

```lua
for i = 1, #CAST_VECTORS do
    local Raycast = workspace:Raycast(stairCFrame.Position, CAST_VECTORS[i], Params)
    if not Raycast or not Raycast.Instance then
        continue
    end

    if not Raycast.Instance.Parent:HasTag("Stair") then
        continue
    end

    local RaycastStair = Raycast.Instance.Parent
    local StairLookVector = stairCFrame.LookVector
    local RaycastLookVector = RaycastStair:GetPivot().LookVector

    -- Do corner stairs
    if StairLookVector.X == 1 then
        if RaycastLookVector.Z == 1 then
            CurrentStyle, CurrentAngle = "Corner", CFrame.Angles(0, 0, 0)
        elseif RaycastLookVector.Z == -1 then
            CurrentStyle, CurrentAngle = "Corner", CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(90), 0)
        end
    elseif StairLookVector.X == -1 then
        if RaycastLookVector.Z == 1 then
            CurrentStyle, CurrentAngle = "Corner", CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(90), 0)
        elseif RaycastLookVector.Z == -1 then
            CurrentStyle, CurrentAngle = "Corner", CFrame.Angles(0, 0, 0)
        end
    elseif StairLookVector.Z == 1 then
        if RaycastLookVector.X == 1 then
            CurrentStyle, CurrentAngle = "Corner", CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(90), 0)
        elseif RaycastLookVector.X == -1 then
            CurrentStyle, CurrentAngle = "Corner", CFrame.Angles(0, 0, 0)
        end
    elseif StairLookVector.Z == -1 then
        if RaycastLookVector.X == 1 then
            CurrentStyle, CurrentAngle = "Corner", CFrame.Angles(0, 0, 0)
        elseif RaycastLookVector.X == -1 then
            CurrentStyle, CurrentAngle = "Corner", CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(90), 0)
        end
    end

    if CurrentStyle == RaycastStair.Name then
        CurrentStyle, CurrentAngle = "Normal", CFrame.Angles(0, 0, 0) -- Revert?
    end
end
```

Is what I kinda have, but it's really clunky, doesn't always work with every use case, and only works on corner stairs at the moment.

I am trying to basically match Minecraft's way of doing stair orientation, however there's no pages anywhere that discuss the math/logic behind how it works.

Looking at Minecraft, can see 2 properties
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGrH4.png)

facing and shape. Instead of tryna do CFrame.Angles() to rotate shape, should I just manually make all the different stair facing and shapes (think there'd be what 4 facing, each face has 2 shapes, so 8 shapes?)

Or is doing the math to just rotate a single Corner Stair model the way to go?

This is with all the stairs modelled

[Stair models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoM8w.png)

[Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usFi8.png)

Models in order, left-right, N S E W from top to bottom